# How much amount of data can be stored in the single instance of mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have single node mongo db instance with 8GB RAM, 500 GB Harddisk,

what is the maximum amount of data that can be stored in the following?

1) Per collection
2) Per database
3) Per MongoDB instance

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/ nothing you have to worry about with your specifications

Comment: More specific you can look at: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#data

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the **WiredTiger** storage engine then there is no restriction on capping of collections, databases on a single instance.

> Only constraint is that the maximum BSON document size is 16MB or 16777216 bytes.

From above one you can calculate the size of collections, db depending one how many collections you have in a database in a instance.

For more information on size and limit depending on the storage engine and version of mongo you are using [click here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#data)